# .get() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, addclass

I apologize if this is a really dumb mistake, but I'm a little new to the .get() function. I used it exactly as was explained on [this](http://api.jquery.com/get/) page, but it did not work as expected. This is the code they used

```
console.log( $( "li" ).get( 0 ) );
```

So I tried to do something to the same effect:

```
$('.a').get(0).addClass('g');
```

Theoretically, this should add the class 'g' to the first element with the class 'a', but it doesn't. I've already manually added the class 'g' to the first element and it does show up, so it's the jQuery that's not working.

jQuery 2.1.0

Comment: In your case you need use http://api.jquery.com/eq/ function not get

Comment: User $('.a').eq(0) OR $('.a :first') instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.fn.get` when not used along with `$.fn.map`, returns an `HTMLElement` that doesn't have `addClass` and many more jQuery methods.

So you must do the below using `eq`(or `:first` based on what you want)

```
$('.a').eq(0).addClass('g'); // assuming you want first .a
```

If you want a native way of doing it(for some weird reason) then you can do

```
$('.a').get(0).className += " g";
// space is important -------^
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.get()` method returns the first element in the jQuery collection's internal array, which is an HTMLElement, and no longer a jQuery object.

To get the first element in the jQuery collection, and retain its type as a jQuery object, use `.eq(0)` instead.

See [jQuery's documentation for the `.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 1):

.get() returns HTMLElement, not a jQuery object (http://api.jquery.com/get/). HTMLElements do not have addClass method. If you want to add class to that DOM element you need to wrap it into $(). This shoul work:

```
$($('.a').get(0)).addClass('g');
```

Or you can just add a new class to the retreived HTMLElement:

```
$('.a').get(0).className += " g";
```